# dynamically changing the playback speed of a sound in as3 without altering pitch

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, arrays, mp3

I'm making a game based on simple song creation, and I'm planning on having a feature where players can listen to the songs they've created with the game. the rhythm of the melody is controlled with a system of timers, but this will not work for the backing track presets I am planning on implementing, as each mp3 file in the backing tracks represents one bar instead of one note.

while it would be possible to use my timer system for playing the backing tracks, this would require several more audio files, much more coding and would push the project far behind schedule. therefore, i need to manipulate the playback speeds of the files I already have. I've commonly seen two examples of how to do this, here: http://2008.kelvinluck.com/2008/11/first-steps-with-flash-10-audio-programming/ and here: http://blog.andre-michelle.com/2009/pitch-mp3/

the problem with both of these is that they also alter the pitch as well. this is a problem for me, as I would very much like players to be able to alter the pitch and tempo of their songs separately. I think the code I need is similar to the examples above, but I'm having trouble understanding those since I haven't had much experience with bytearrays and such. I'd like to be able to understand the examples i included so that I can figure out what I need to do in order to get my game working the way it should, but help of any sort is appreciated. thank you =)

Comment: Your project is doomed to start with as Flash technology is the worst on the market for any sound related or sound edition related app due to its very high latency in sound playing. This being said the only way to alter the speed of playback is by extracting the raw data of a sound and alter its speed within the SOUND_DATA event. In that case the latency can easily get beyond 1000ms while classic ,mp3 playback can go from 50ms to 500ms. The required industry standard max limit is at 30ms, Flash technology cannot reach that number.

Comment: please i need to get this done for an assignment + its only a prototype so it doesnt need to be industry standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try https://github.com/also/soundtouch-as3
there is an early (alpha) demo at http://static.ryanberdeen.com/projects/soundtouch-as3/demo/player/stretch.swf
quality is "acceptable" if you are using 1.0x-1.5x factor (less than 1.0 gives very artificial distortion)

Comment: this seems like it'll work perfectly for what i need, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You could also try :

http://iq12.com/old_blog/2009/08/25/real-time-pitch-shifting/

test : **[Online demo](http://vcone.co.uk/public/StackOverflow/PitchShift_v1.swf)**

Their online demo didn't load a track for me (deleted MP3?), so I put a recompiled SWF on my server just for testing. It loads **[this MP3 audio clip](http://vcone.co.uk/public/StackOverflow/test.mp3)**, if you wanna compare results to original sound.

It aims to preserve audio length (time scale) whilst **adjusting pitch** (deeper when slow or higher when faster). You could possibly combine this with Kelvin Luck's **[Second Steps...](http://2008.kelvinluck.com/2009/03/second-steps-with-flash-10-audio-programming/)**. Thereby having example codes for speed and pitch.

It was inspired by some `C#` code ported from this `C` **[code](http://blogs.zynaptiq.com/bernsee/repo/smbPitchShift.cpp)** as found at (with concept explanation) : 
  http://blogs.zynaptiq.com/bernsee/pitch-shifting-using-the-ft/